# Не работают события

Tags: javascript

Почему в данном примере консоль выдаёт ошибку?

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var myList = document.getElementById("list");

function addItem(){
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    newLi.innerHTML = "Новая задача";
    newLi.className = "item";
    myList.appendClild(newLi);

}


num1.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: не `myList.appendClild(newLi);` а `myList.appendChild(newLi);` опечатка в команде

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка показывает, что `num1` равна `null`, поэтому у данной переменной (читать объекта) нет метода `addEventListener`.

Проверьте наличие элемента с `id="btn1"`.

Comment: Оказалось, проблема в том, что скрипт был объявлен в head